# What does this $[\mu]$ mean here?

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

[image]

Here's what those notation means
[image]

This $"[\mu]"$ makes the setence weird and I don't understand what it means
Please help
Here's the link of the whole paper, and this is at page 151 https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.acta/1485892007

Comment: Do you know what “almost all” means in measure theory? It is defined with respect to a measure, so ...

Comment: I'm understanding almost all as the whole thing except the null?

Comment: If you are satisfied with the answers, please mark one of them as accepted to help other people know that your question is answered. If not, please comment what is missing.

Answer (score 3):

Almost all means the set of $x\in X$ you are looking at is **all elements but a set with measurement $0$**.

However, the notion of measurement $0$ depends on the measure $\mu$ you are using. So the $[\mu]$ in the theorem is supposed to remind you of that fact.

Note that the measurement $0$ can be way more than just the $0$ element!

For example with the standard Lebesgue measure $\mu$ the set $\mathbb{Q}$ is a $0$-measure subset of $\mathbb{R}$!

Answer (score 1):

This "$[\mu]$" is used as a part of the following equivalent constructions:

-"almost all $[\mu]$"

-"almost everywhere $[\mu]$"

-"almost surely $[\mu]$"

Their meaning is the following:

If we say, that almost all $[\mu]$ elements of a measurable space $(X, \Omega, \mu)$ have some property, that means that the measure $\mu$ of the set of all elements of it that do not have this property is equal to zero.

We write $[\mu]$ here, to explicitly say what measure were we talking about, as having several distinct non-equivalent measures can otherwise lead to confusion:

For example, almost all real numbers are non-zero under [Lebesgue measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_measure), but almost all of them are zero under the corresponding [Dirac measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_measure).